# how to make an average with SD across all combination

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data like this

```
    df<- structure(list(data = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "AB", "ABN", "AHG", 
"ANBV"), G1_1 = c(1677.1, 956, 57.7, 44.5, 1578.2, 1184.8, 1958.5
), G1_2 = c(1296.9, 1230.2, 68.4, 57.5, 925.1, 1275.7, 2143.6
), G2_1 = c(7012.5, 2087.9, 146.7, 80, 6278.5, 3076.9, 808), 
    G2_2 = c(13470.8, 3926.6, 226.5, 212.6, 12569.4, 6569, 2479.8
    ), Vok3_1 = c(911, 832.8, 50.8, 34.8, 916.6, 1358.5, 1540.4
    ), Vok3_2 = c(5121.9, 1029.6, 108.9, 135, 3624.5, 1971.3, 
    1851.4), Vok4_1 = c(5136.7, 892.1, 78, 60.4, 3106.6, 1578.6, 
    1132.1), Vok4_2 = c(6313.4, 1180.8, 112, 163.4, 4639.8, 2506.4, 
    879.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

what I am trying to do is to get the sd and median, I am unsuccessful

here is what I try and what I am looking to get

```
df_med <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(data = substr(data, 1, 2,3,4)) %>% summarise_all(funs(median)))
```

here is the way I want is to get the median or sd between each two column for each row , for instance the first two columns G1_1 and G1_2 and between G2_1 and G2_2 etc

The output that I look for is like this

```
data    G1        G2         Vok3          Vok4
A       1487    10241.65    3016.45   5725.05
AA     1093.1   3007.25    931.2      1036.45
AAA    63.05    186.6      79.85       95
AB      51      146.3       84.9       111.9
ABN    1251.65  9423.95     2270.55   3873.2
AHG   1230.25   4822.95.    1664.9    2042.5
ANBV    2051.05 1643.9      1695.9    1005.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to reshape to 'long' (`pivot_longer`)before doing a group by `summarise`

1. Reshape the columns to 'long' except the first 'data' column, capture the substring in the column names before the `_` in `names_pattern`
2. Grouped by 'data', `summarise` `across` all the other columns to get the `median`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_median <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -data, names_to = ".value",
        names_pattern = "(.*)_\\d+") %>% 
    group_by(data) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), median, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
df_median
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  data      G1     G2   Vok3  Vok4
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     1487   10242. 3016.  5725.
2 AA    1093.   3007.  931.  1036.
3 AAA     63.0   187.   79.8   95 
4 AB      51     146.   84.9  112.
5 ABN   1252.   9424. 2271.  3873.
6 AHG   1230.   4823. 1665.  2042.
7 ANBV  2051.   1644. 1696.  1006.
```

From the wide format, we can again convert to 'long' as

```
df_median %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -data, names_to = 'key') %>% 
   arrange(data)
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   data  key     value
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A     G1     1487  
 2 A     G2    10242. 
 3 A     Vok3   3016. 
 4 A     Vok4   5725. 
 5 AA    G1     1093. 
 6 AA    G2     3007. 
 7 AA    Vok3    931. 
 8 AA    Vok4   1036. 
 9 AAA   G1       63.0
10 AAA   G2      187. 
# … with 18 more rows
```

---

Or instead of doing this in two separate steps, we do the reshaping on all columns, then get the substring of 'key' column and use in grouping to get the `median` of 'value'

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -data, names_to = "key") %>%
   group_by(data, key = str_remove(key, "_\\d+")) %>% 
   summarise(value = median(value), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   data  key     value
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A     G1     1487  
 2 A     G2    10242. 
 3 A     Vok3   3016. 
 4 A     Vok4   5725. 
 5 AA    G1     1093. 
 6 AA    G2     3007. 
 7 AA    Vok3    931. 
 8 AA    Vok4   1036. 
 9 AAA   G1       63.0
10 AAA   G2      187. 
# … with 18 more rows
```

---

If the `dplyr` version is old, then use `summarise_all`

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -data, names_to = ".value",
        names_pattern = "(.*)_\\d+") %>% 
    group_by(data) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_all(median, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  data      G1     G2   Vok3  Vok4
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     1487   10242. 3016.  5725.
2 AA    1093.   3007.  931.  1036.
3 AAA     63.0   187.   79.8   95 
4 AB      51     146.   84.9  112.
5 ABN   1252.   9424. 2271.  3873.
6 AHG   1230.   4823. 1665.  2042.
7 ANBV  2051.   1644. 1696.  1006.
```

---

Or use `split.default` from `base R` into a `list` of data.frames, use `rowMedians` from `matrixStats` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
cbind(df[1], sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub("_\\d+$", "", names(df)[-1])), 
       function(x) rowMedians(as.matrix(x))))
data      G1       G2    Vok3    Vok4
1    A 1487.00 10241.65 3016.45 5725.05
2   AA 1093.10  3007.25  931.20 1036.45
3  AAA   63.05   186.60   79.85   95.00
4   AB   51.00   146.30   84.90  111.90
5  ABN 1251.65  9423.95 2270.55 3873.20
6  AHG 1230.25  4822.95 1664.90 2042.50
7 ANBV 2051.05  1643.90 1695.90 1005.60
```

Comment: I got this error `Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @Learner try adding `dplyr::summarise` I assume that your `dplyr` version is >= 1.0.0

Comment: is there a way to make it long? `gather(df_median, key, value, -c(data)) %>% arrange(data)' I already accept you answer but I would like it if you could help me to make it long I used the df_median as being the output of your command

Comment: @Learner Sorry, I didn't understand your question.  I used `pivot_longer` to make it long.  `gather` is deprecated and `pivot_longer` is more flexible and have added functionalities

Comment: @Learner If you want to make it longer from the output then `df_median %>% pivot_longer(cols = -data)`

Comment: at the end I am trying to make this data as long with characters like "data", value, key you know spreading it

Comment: @Learner I updated the post.  Can you please check

Comment: @Learner I added one more solution to do this more compactly

Comment: I just accepted and liked your answer. THANK YOU